# How to get the number of active DB connections made from spring boot application

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot

I have build a spring boot application with Oracle datasource. I need to print the total active connections in log statement. How to get the active connections. Note - Not max active connections it should be active connection @particular time/instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
LOGGER.info("Max Idle: " + dataSource.getMaxIdle());
LOGGER.info("Max Active: " + dataSource.getMaxIdle());
LOGGER.info("Active: " + dataSource.getNumActive());
LOGGER.info("Idle: " + dataSource.getNumIdle());
```

Refered From this link - https://numberformat.wordpress.com/2017/10/20/configuring-a-connection-pool-in-spring-using-dbcp2/

#### Edit

##### Answer 2:

For HikariCP you have to enable the `debug` level logs for the package `com.zaxxer.hikari` this will print the stats for every 30 seconds.

Comment: This is not working in Spring boot 2.0.3 version. because in this version by default connection pool is HickariCP. and if you set property spring.jpa.open-in-view=false this method wont work.

Comment: @Coder For HikariCP you have to enable the debug logs for the package `com.zaxxer.hikari` this will print the stats for every 30 seconds

Comment: Website link is dead

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon the actual connection pool used ( like dbcp2 etc) in your configuration you can try to set the logging level of the pool package to debug/trace and see if the pool provides this information for you. Typically pools provides this info. Another option you have is that usually the datasource you are using with Spring Boot would be registering itself to JMX as `MBeans` which has a property "`NumActive`" along with others like `"MaxActive"` etc. You can write a timer code in your application which fires at specific time interval , queries the JMX MBean and prints the info in the logs. To check for the available data in MBeans you can hook up VisualVM/JConsole to your app and visit the MBeans tab.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. Am using default connection pool (Tomcat connection pool). How to get the connection pool object in spring boot. Am new to this spring boot that's why.

Comment: This fixed my issue 
`DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();`
`LOGGER.info("Max Idle: " + dataSource.getMaxIdle());
  LOGGER.info("Max Active: " + dataSource.getMaxIdle());
  LOGGER.info("Active: " + dataSource.getNumActive());
  LOGGER.info("Idle: " + dataSource.getNumIdle());`
[https://numberformat.wordpress.com/2017/10/20/configuring-a-connection-pool-in-spring-using-dbcp2/](https://numberformat.wordpress.com/2017/10/20/configuring-a-connection-pool-in-spring-using-dbcp2/)